# not all code paths return a value in c#

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to make clap programe for kinect in  c# but I'm getting this error "not all code paths return a value " for the GetJointDistance method 
here is my method

Comment: Your method that's supposed to return `float` doesn't have a single `return` statement in it.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Did you read the actual words in it? (Although it could be better: "No code paths return a value" would be more specific.) It's quite important to get past the word "Error" and **read the actual message itself** - the message has meaning, and usually they're pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have written supposedly returns a `float`:

```
private float GetJointDistance
```

However, your method body doesn't have **any** `return` statements - so not only do not all code paths return a value, **none** do.

You should fix this by adding a return:

```
private float GetJointDistance(Joint handR, Joint handL)
{
    Skeleton s = new Skeleton(); 
    Joint handRight = s.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
    Joint handLeft = s.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]; 
    if (handRight.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked &&
    handLeft.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
    {
        this.GetJointDistance(handRight, handLeft);
    }

    return xyz;     // xyz must be a float

}
```

Note that if your `if` statement means you need to return something else you need a second `return` in the `if` statement. Although you're quite likely to overflow the stack at the moment, depending on how often the state is `Tracked`.

Alternatively, make your method return `void` as you don't seem to need a return at the moment:

```
private void GetJointDistance
```